# Javac compiling issue

Tags: java, javac

I came up with the following error when trying to compile a project which has the annotations `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)`

> Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
>   An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.6.0_20).
>
> Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic
>   Thank you.
>
> tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure : class file for javax.persistence.AccessType not found. Build error

How do I fix this error in the java parser?
I am using elcipselink and eclipse as the IDE.

Comment: probably `ejb3-persistence.jar` is missing in your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Could be your version of the JPA JAR: this annotation has been used only since JPA 2.0, according to the javadocs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AccessType.html

Comment: Can you find that annotation in a JAR that's in your CLASSPATH?  If not, the class loader won't be able to, either.

Comment: Yes, the jar is in my classpath and I able to reach the @Access annotation code when I press Ctrl + right mouse click.However the javac compiler is giving me a problem.

Comment: Can you compile this successfully in a command shell, without Eclipse?  Do you have a JDK installed that's different from the version Eclipse is using?

Comment: may be you have `hibernate-jpa` jar in the classpath too. This also has `javax.persistence.Access` and `javax.persistence.AccessType`

Comment: All of the above answers are 'No'.

Comment: You can't compile without Eclipse?  That's a problem.  Get an alternative JDK and take Eclipse out of the equation.  You should not be overly dependent on any IDE.

Comment: The jar is there on the classpath but the compiler cannot find it.That's the problem.

Comment: When you say compiler can't find it what do you mean? Did you write import statement `import javax.persistence.AccessType;` and compiler has issues with this? Generally I have seen in eclipse, I can't right click on class names which is inside bracket.